# What does predicate mean in C?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
int (*predicate)(char) = 0;
```

Can anyone tell me what this code means? What is the meaning of the word `predicate` in C?

Comment: As @Rob's answer notes, C itself attaches no significance to this identifier.  However it's likely that _predicate_ has been chosen by the programmer to document that this is a predicate in the [LISP sense](http://www.cliki.net/Naming+conventions): a function that tests something about its arguments and returns true/false.  See also the [-P convention](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/p-convention.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence is a declaration and definition of a pointer to a function taking one argument (char) and returning int. The pointer is initialized to the null pointer value.

The word "predicate" is the programmer's choice for the variable name.

Reference: [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28%2apredicate%29%28char%29%3B)

One might use `predicate` like this:

```
/* UNTESTED */
int IsLower(char c) { return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'; }
int main () {
    int (*predicate)(char);

    predicate = IsLower;

    if ( (*predicate)('f') == 1 ) printf("'f' is lower case!\n");
}
```

Comment: So this means i can use any variable name like `predicate`, there is no special meaning of `predicate` ?

Comment: Yes, there is no special meaning to "predicate". It could have been named "p", "pointer_to_function", or "George" to equal effect.